# Qt Inter-Process function trigger

Tags: c++, qt5

I know I can use [QSharedMemory](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsharedmemory.html) to transfer information between applications (I've used it successfully). **But I'd like to trigger a function on another application.** Ex: App1 has a button that when pressed triggers a function on App2 that prints "HelloWorld".

I've checked [IPC](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/ipc.html) solutions' page and I see that linux supports D-Bus communications and Qt uses it to extend signals and slots to IPC level, which is essentially the kind of thing I want. But I'm working on Windows for now and need a solution that is compatible with both OSs.

I also see that perhaps I could use [TCP/IP solutions in Qt library](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtnetwork-index.html) to establish a server/client communication, but given that I'm not so versed in it I'd prefer something simpler. But maybe TCP/IP is quite simple and with a few variables and functions calls I could get it done. Please tell me if that's the case.

I've also thought of using a boolean variable on [QSharedMemory](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsharedmemory.html) that is set by the master app and is regularly checked and cleared by the slave app when a timer, running on a loop, runs out. But that means more overhead. It's not at all a clean solution, but it would work ok in my case.

Comment: if both apps run on same device i'd say use udp. I'm pretty sure there is good excample in Qt docks on QUdpSocket.

Comment: Well researched question and you put some thought into it, but it seems too general for SO. Perhaps try Software Engineering?

Comment: I haven't used it myself but... [Qt Remote Objects](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtremoteobjects-index.html) might be worth a look.

Comment: You could inject a dll and trigger the button click. But there may be an easier way.

Comment: Does Windows have *named pipes*? They could be an option.